# ASN1 декодер в Java. Как использовать?

Tags: java, apache

Есть строка, закодированная в asn1 (Примера не будет). Без проблем разбирает первым попавшимся онлайн-декодером.
Но нужно добавить функционал в java.

Пытаюсь понять как использовать библиотеку

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.directory.api</groupId>
        <artifactId>api-asn1-ber</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

Интересует метод Asn1Decoder с сигнатурой

```
public static void decode(ByteBuffer stream, Asn1Container container)
```

Вопрос: Что такое этот контейнер, как мне его проинициализировать, какими данными наполнять?

Comment: Для начала стоит уяснить, что ASN.1 - это язык для описания данных, а закодирована строка одним из возможных видов кодирования, таких как BER и что для разбора таких данных вам потребуется соответствующее их описание на ASN.1.

Comment: У меня есть описание данных, вот только это описание никак не проясняет мне как создать контейнер.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо за ответы. У меня еще на момент написания вопроса было подозрение, что мне нужно реализовать свои класс-наследник контейнера, но загвоздка как раз в том и была, что я не смогла соотнести схему с теми полями, которые объявлены в абстрактном контейнере, не говоря уже об отсутствии понимания что именно мне нужно прописать в своем.

Рабочее решение для декодера удалось реализовать с использованием другой библиотеки

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
        <artifactId>bcprov-jdk16</artifactId>
        <version>1.46</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

смотрим [документацию](https://nightlies.apache.org/directory/api/2.1.4/apidocs/org/apache/directory/api/asn1/ber/Asn1Decoder.html#decode-java.nio.ByteBuffer-org.apache.directory.api.asn1.ber.Asn1Container-) метода:

> container - The container that store the state, the result and other elements.

читаем [документацию Asn1Container](https://nightlies.apache.org/directory/api/2.1.4/apidocs/org/apache/directory/api/asn1/ber/Asn1Container.html):

> All Known Implementing Classes:
> AbstractContainer, AdDirSyncRequestContainer, AdDirSyncResponseContainer, AdPolicyHintsContainer, CancelRequestContainer, CertGenerationRequestContainer, ControlsContainer, EndTransactionRequestContainer, EndTransactionResponseContainer, EntryChangeContainer, GracefulDisconnectResponseContainer, GracefulShutdownRequestContainer, LdapMessageContainer, PagedResultsContainer, PasswordModifyRequestContainer, PasswordModifyResponseContainer, PasswordPolicyResponseContainer, PersistentSearchContainer, SortRequestContainer, SortResponseContainer, StoredProcedureRequestContainer, SubentriesContainer, SyncDoneValueContainer, SyncInfoValueContainer, SyncRequestValueContainer, SyncStateValueContainer, VirtualListViewRequestContainer, VirtualListViewResponseContainer

т.о. в зависимости от юзкейса, используем подходящий класс из этого списка или имплементим свой, наследуясь от AbstractContainer.

// примера не будет :)